# Beginner Android Studio: Unexpected Tokens?

Tags: android

I'm learning to create some basic apps in Android Studio. Right now I'm working on learning the concept of "Echoing". I'm having trouble with my professor's code that was given to me, here it is in activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me multiple errors, most of them saying Unexpected tokens, or Error:(3) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token). What is wrong with this basic xml?

Comment: There seems to be no error in your code. It works fine for me. This error occurs due to a spelling mistake/a spurious character/an incorrect namespace. The error may be present in a different xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem with sync gradle and there is no issue with XML that you posted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The above / Your XML Code works well for anyone. Sync the Gradle and try running the app again. If you still facing the same problem then create new project and place the above/your XML and java code in that new project

Comment: Thank you, I remade the project and Synced the Gradle and it fixed it.